# sql oracle - import text file

Tags: sql, oracle

I know this question is frequently asked, but I can't manage it myself.

I have a single column data text file stored at my desktop. (C:\Users\Desktop) 
The file is called ids.txt.

First I made a table in sql called tmp_target_ids with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_target_ids
(ids number(9,0));
```

Now I want to load the text file into this table, but can't figure out why it doesn't work.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Desktop/ids.txt' 
INTO TABLE tmp_target_ids COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

How do I load my local data into the sql database?

Update: I use Oracle, and i manage to load the data manually, but still would like to have a script

Comment: Where [in the Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find `load data`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - A lovely side-effect of Oracle purchasing Sun... :-) e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.0-en/load-data.html

Comment: Are you using a local Oracle server?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL - In January 2008, Sun Microsystems bought MySQL for $1 billion.[53]

In April 2009, Oracle Corporation entered into an agreement to purchase Sun Microsystems,[54] then owners of MySQL copyright and trademark.

Comment: on which machine is the data you try to read into the database and on which machine is the database running? Do you have access to the sqlldr tool on the machine where the data is placed?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can use SQLLoader to load this file, you may write a CTL file like:

**d:\ids.ctl**:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'd:\ids.txt' 
INTO TABLE tmp_target_ids
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
(
    ids
)
```

Saying that you have to load a file like the following:

**d:\ids.txt**:

```
10  
100 
999
```

If you run the following:

```
sqlldr user/password@yourInstanceName d:\ids.ctl
```

this is what you get:

```
SQL> select * from tmp_target_ids;

       IDS
----------
        10
       100
       999
```

Comment: I tried, the first script tells me: missing SELECT keyword, referring to ids.

Comment: This is not a script, but a CTL file to be used in SQLLoader. If you follow all the steps, by saving that part in a file and then running SQLLoader as showed, Loader will load the text file into your table

Comment: I'm new to sql, so I don't know if I used the sqlloader already when I said I loaded the data manually (data import wizard?). Is it possible that there is a script underneath the create table to load data into the table? So I can just press run, and the data is loaded?

Comment: It depends on the tool you are using. Wizard of what? Toad,SQLDeveloper, PLSQLDeveloper, ... ?. For example, TOAD even builds a CTL file to be used with SQLLoader, because SQLLoader is much more efficient than Toad itself to load big files. The best way (IMHO) to load a file in a table is SQLLoader, and it's not that difficult. I just showed you how to build a CTL file and how to launch Loader, you just have to write the file I gave and run

Comment: I used this: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Import_Export/sqldev3.0_import_export.htm#t3